# Can I format the style of the unit test output in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, formatting

This serves absolutely no purpose aside from readability and presentation but, I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to format the results of the output (via `TestContext.WriteLine`, `Trace.WriteLine`, `Debug.WriteLine`, `Console.WriteLine`, etc...) of my unit tests in Visual Studio 2010?

To give whatever justification I can, I'm basically trying to make the result more human readable and friendly. I had little success using spaces because the font in the report isn't mono-spaced and I couldn't find where to change it. I know that it reads at least some character codes because it recognizes `\t`.

My last resort is to output HTML and just save it to an external file, but if at all possible I'd really like to keep everything inside of Visual Studio.

Thanks! 
Jason

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Console.Writeline to write information from your unit tests.  It will appear in the result window of the specific test.  I didn't get too fancy, but the string.format method works fine.

The output appears in both the default visual studio unit test window as well as Resharper's test runner.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm currently using String.Format and don't have any problems outputting values--what I'm looking to do is alter the appearance of the output (i.e. color, weight and position).

Comment: Based on some of the testing I did in my test project, this does not appear to be possible.  It looks like the only formatting you can do is something akin to ASCII art.